# JSF, registering null value to bound instances

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm having trouble assigning the value null to a bound instance. Whenever a selection is made within the selectOneMenu everything works as expected (the instance registered as cc.attrs.city is set to the selected value, as shown in example below), however when selecting the hardcoded null value, I'm examining that my selection is not forwarded to the bound instance. Any help would be appriciated.

Usage example :

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{cc.attrs.city}"
                     converter="anySelectConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['general.choose']}" itemValue="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{city.name}" itemValue="#{city}"
                       var="city" value="#{locationComponentController.getAllCities()}" />
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="district subdistrict village neighbourhood #{cc.attrs.updateOnSelection}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Any select converter :

```
@FacesConverter("anySelectConverter")
public class AnySelectConverter implements Converter{


     private static Map<Object, String> entities = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, String>();

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {

            // TODO : Geçici çözüm sebebi araştırılmalı
            if(entity == null)
                return "";

            synchronized (entities) {
                if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    entities.put(entity, uuid);
                    return uuid;
                } else {
                    return entities.get(entity);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
            for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                    return entry.getKey();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have a required=true on your cc attribute?

Comment: I do have it, would that be a problem ?

Comment: I have removed all required=true from the attributes, didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try designating the null item as a noSelectionOption, since it looks like that's your intention anyway:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{cc.attrs.city}"
                 converter="anySelectConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['general.choose']}" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{city.name}" itemValue="#{city}"
                   var="city" value="#{locationComponentController.getAllCities()}" />
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="district subdistrict village neighbourhood #{cc.attrs.updateOnSelection}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, when I reselect the default selectItem with the null value, I still don't trigger getAsObject and the bound instance is still not set to null.

Comment: can you try adding city to the update="" of p:ajax? I can't tell if your ajax call is actually sending the dropdown value to the server or not just by looking at the partial code you provided.